# How to get notified when a client connects or disconnects in netty?

Tags: java, netty

I want to get notified whenever a client(browser is my client here) connects or disconnects from the netty server. I have extended SimpleChannelInboundHandler and i m working on websockets so overiding channelActive and channelInactive method would solve my problem? And if yes then please help me out or if there is any other way to achieve it.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes channelActive(...) and channelInactive(...) will be notified when the tcp connection is established and closed.

Comment: can you please provide me the implementation of any one of the above two methods. I want to print the ip whenever a new client joins. I have implemented the code of getting the ip and printing it on the socket but i don't know how to do it as soon as a new client joins

Comment: public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws       Exception {
    channels.writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame("welcome"));
    channels.add(ctx.channel());
    ctx.fireChannelActive();
    } (*channels is the channel group)

Comment: Please take the time to read at least the javadocs.... You can get it via ctx.channel().remoteAddress().